# What kind of sequence is that ($1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^k$) and how it can be expressed in a short way?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am curious what kind of sequence is that
$$1+2+2^2+2^3 +\cdots+2^{k-1}$$
and how it can be simplified or expressed in some short way...
In the classroom we expressed it as $2^{k-1}$ over something (I do not remember exactly).
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$1+2+2^2+\dots + 2^n=2^{n+1}-1$. The number in binary is $\underbrace{11\dots 1}_\text{n+1 times}$. Which is the number that comes before $1\underbrace{00\dots 0}_\text{n+1 zeros}=2^{n+1}$

It is also a very special case of the geometric sum $a^0+a^1+a^2\dots+a^n=\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$ when $a=2$.

The formula can also be re-written to yield the factorization $a^{n+1}-1=(a-1)(a^0+a^1+\dots +a^n)$